# Постановка знака препинания

Tags: пунктуация

На выставке я смог увидеть картины различных художников: портрет трехлетнего Пушкина, написанный неизвестным автором, портреты, выполненные современниками Пушкина Тропининым и Кипренским, картины современных художников. 
Нужен ли знак препинания перед Тропининым?

Comment: Конечно, всё правильно сказал Niemand. Говорится о современниках и потом они называются, поэтому никаких ни запятой, ни тире совершенно не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Не нужен. Нет причин считать это уточнением, обычное приложение. Вместо "различных" лучше "разных".

А-а, еще возможно тире?! Нет, тоже не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы тире всё-таки поставил. Для выразительности. И ещё, может быть, между "автором" и "портреты" вместо запятой поставил, скажем, точку с запятой.

Comment: Зачем? Да, ошибки не будет, но что это тире Вам даст?

Comment: Большую паузу между Пушкиным и Тропининым при чтении. Что, в общем-то, тут и требуется, чтобы логически отделить одно от другого. Прочитайте вслух эту фразу. Там как раз должна быть большая пауза.     (Абсолютно солидарен с Екатериной в этом вопросе)

Answer (score 0):

Тире нужно. В вашем случае приложение - имя собственное - стоит в конце предложения, что служит поводом выделения его при помощи тире. Такие приложения носят пояснительный, разъяснительный характер, перед ними можно вставить слова **а именно** (без изменения смысла):

Обособляются (знаками тире или запятыми) приложения, выраженные именами собственными и относящиеся к нарицательным существительным. Такие приложения имеют уточняющий характер и располагаются после определяемых слов.

См. : Полный академический справочник.

Answer (score 0):

***На выставке я смог увидеть картины различных художников: портрет трехлетнего Пушкина, написанный неизвестным автором; портреты, выполненные современниками Пушкина - Тропининым и Кипренским; картины современных художников.***

Однородные члены распространены и осложнены, поэтому после них нужно поставить точку с запятой. (***§ 132. Точка с запятой ставится между распространёнными однородными членами предложения, особенно если внутри хотя бы одного из них есть запятые***. [здесь](http://www.rusyaz.ru/pr/ptz.html))

***Тире*** перед фамилиями художников можно поставить, так как это однородные нераспространённые приложения, стоящие после определяемого слова. Можно, конечно,  и не ставить.

Обратите внимание на тавтологию (*современниками и современных*).

Comment: Не чувствуете, что с точками с запятой у вас получился как бы реестр? такой список? Не хватает только "итого".

Comment: Ничуть. Уверена, что в данном предложении знаки должны быть поставлены именно так. Правда, тире можно и не ставить.Но я с уважением отношусь и к другим мнениям на этот счёт.

Comment: Екатерина, а есть правило, которое позволяет не ставить тире в этом случае? Я в правилах не нашел.

Comment: Если тире не ставить, то определяемыми словами станут фамилии художников, а приложением - современники Пушкина.  А с тире фамилии являются приложениями. Ср.: ученики Петров и Сидоров.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо..